# Is it possible create a string in the JNI that uses the JVM string pool on Android?

Tags: java, android, jvm, java-native-interface

I understand that in Java creating a string via `new String("foo")` creates a new copy, rather than potentially using an existing one from the string pool. I assume this is also the case in the JNI for `env->NewString("foo", 3)` or `env->NewStringUTF("foo")`, based on the documentation: `"Constructs a new java.lang.String object from an array of Unicode characters."` Likewise, I assume that creating a native string is also allocated entirely separately: `std::string bar = "foo";`, since native allocations don't use the heap.

You could obviously have a variable in Java (ie. `String bar = "foo";`) that is a potential reference to a copy in the string pool, and pass it into the JNI as a jstring. I'm curious if there is any way to create a string entirely within the JNI that can potentially use the JVM string pool? If not, are there any best practices or recommendations on how to minimize memory usage for code that creates/processes a large number of strings which are passed across the JNI layer (in both directions) for many operations?

*Side note:* I understand crossing the JNI layer is expensive, and that the basic situation I'm describing adds increased expenses for memory allocation. Unfortunately, this is part of building a "thin" Java surface for an existing C++ library to consume as an Android library, so at best I'm trying to find ways to optimize things as well as I can.

Comment: Create a regular Java String and use the JVM flag: `-XX:+UseStringDeduplication`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this is for Android. Question and tags updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Intern it:

```
jstring s = env->NewStringUTF("foo");
s = env->CallObjectMethod(s, internID);
```

where `internID` is the previously obtained `methodID` of `String.intern()`.